# Changing People Picker scope (for resolving entities) in SharePoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I've a custom application page test.aspx. I've a people picker in test.aspx.

I open the page with the url `http://site01/_layouts/test.aspx` and I want the people picker to resolve the SharePoint groups in the site `http://site02`.

By default the people picker resolves the entities belonging to the current site collection. How can I change the scope to a different site collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it can't be done. All I'm getting when researching about people picker scope is this - http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/08/30/limiting-people-picker-scope-in-sharepoint/.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to manuly create one constant string in class and assign  static url from which you want to check the people picker user entity.

for ex:

public constant string url="http://site02";

SPSite site=new SPSite(url);

hope this helps.

Comment: Where are you using that URL with People Picker? What am I going to do with that variable?

Comment: follow this link for better understanding: http://msnwindowslive.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!DA44120081017B95!1712.entry  hope this help

Comment: Sorry. You don't seem to understand my question. I want to set the scope of the people picker in which it resolves the entities.

Comment: hey i know your question, but they above link will soved your problem programatically. if you want to resolve the people picker entities. any way... go through this link. this may help what you want : http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--setup-upgrade-administration-operation/performance-issue-with-people-picker-18079.shtml

Comment: I don't think either of your links answers my question. Where is it talked about changing the scope of the people picker programmatically?